# How to set selected populated select option

Tags: php, mysql, select-options

I want to ask something regarding my codes. In MySQL database, there are two tables which are table 'Team' and table 'Borrower'.

Below is the image of table 'Team'

[image]

And below is the image of table 'Borrower'

[image]

AT PHP page, User can edit info of any User's details including their team. From the table above, Namron team_id is 3 which is team 'burner'. But at the page, how I want to display at Team select option, will list all team that have at table 'Team' but selected is 'burner' since this is current team for Namron.

Below is my current code.

borrower_details.php

```
<?php

    $badgeid = $_POST['badgeid'];

    $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM ets_borrower 
                INNER JOIN ets_team ON ets_borrower.team_id = ets_team.team_id 
            WHERE ets_borrower.status_id = 1 
              AND ets_borrower.badgeid = :badgeid 
            ORDER BY ets_borrower.fullname ASC";
    
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':badgeid' => $badgeid));
    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $badgeid = $row["badgeid"];
        $fullname = $row["fullname"];
        $team_id = $row["team_id"];
        $team_name = $row["team_name"];
    }

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM ets_team WHERE status = 1";
    $query2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);
    $query2->execute();

    while($row2 = $query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    
        $team_id2 = $row2["team_id"];
        $team_name2 = $row2["team_name"];

?>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label for="example-search-input">Badge ID</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="badgeid" value="<?php echo $badgeid; ?>" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label for="example-search-input">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fullname" value="<?php echo strtoupper($fullname); ?>" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label for="example-search-input">Team</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="team_id">
                <option value="<?php echo $team_id;?>" <?php echo $team_id2 == $team_id? 'selected': '';?> ><?php echo $team_name2;?></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: As you have opened a loop in PHP and generate various HTML elements within said loop you cannot repeat ID attributes - `exampleFormControlSelect1` cannot be assigned repeatedly as the ID to different `select` menus.

Comment: The initial sql query reassigns the variables within the loop so if there is more than one result from the query you will only have a single value later when you attempt to do your comparison or use these variables in the various form elements...

Comment: Is `ets_borrower.badgeid` Unique?

Comment: Dont understand why the `<select.....>` and `<option...>` are both INSIDE the while loop. That will create MULTIPLE `<select>` dropdowns each with only ONE option in them ???

Comment: @RiggsFolly, thats why I ask. Need your help

Comment: Is your first query supposed to return ONLY ONE row?

Comment: @RiggsFolly. Yes. Like my question above. When I want to edit User Namron, and, at dropdown list, it will populate all team name from table teams, but selected is 'burner', which is teams_id = 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your while loop below select tag.

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="team_id">
<?php
while($row2 = $query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $team_id2 = $row2["team_id"];
        $team_name2 = $row2["team_name"];
?>
<option value="<?php echo $team_id;?>" <?php echo $team_id2 == $team_id? 'selected': '';?> ><?php echo $team_name2;?></option>
<?php }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the comments in the code for detail.

Basically you have to move the while loop that is supposed to load the dropdown list to only where the list of options are to be loaded

```
$badgeid = $_POST['badgeid'];

$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM ets_borrower 
            INNER JOIN ets_team ON ets_borrower.team_id = ets_team.team_id 
        WHERE ets_borrower.status_id = 1 
          AND ets_borrower.badgeid = :badgeid 
        ORDER BY ets_borrower.fullname ASC";

$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(':badgeid' => $badgeid));

// while loop not require, only one row can be returned
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$badgeid = $row["badgeid"];
$fullname = $row["fullname"];
$team_id = $row["team_id"];
$team_name = $row["team_name"];

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM ets_team WHERE status = 1";
$query2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);
$query2->execute();
// while loop moved down to load just the dropdown
?>

<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <label for="example-search-input">Badge ID</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="badgeid" value="<?php echo $badgeid; ?>" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <label for="example-search-input">Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fullname" value="<?php echo strtoupper($fullname); ?>" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <label for="example-search-input">Team</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="team_id">
<?php
while($row2 = $query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) :

    $sel = $team_id2 == $team_id? 'selected' : '';
    echo "<option value='$team_id' $sel>$row2[team_name]</option>";
endwhile;
?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where the '$row' declacred at $badgeid = $row["badgeid"];?

Comment: and also $row2 ?

Comment: Sorry, typo on the `$row` missed a line out, sotty

Comment: `$row2`, the whole loop was moved to the place where you are loading the `<option>` tags

Comment: still cannot, Team selected should be 'burner' but currently it selected the first team list which is 'jba'

Comment: What are you passing in to the code on `$_POST['badgeid']`